# Value returned by strtok() for tokens of length 0?

Tags: c++, string, strtok

I have the following piece of C++ code:

```
string dots="...";
char *points=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
strcpy(points,dots.c_str());
points=strtok(points,".");
while(points!=NULL)
{
cout<<points<<endl;
points=strtok(NULL,".");
}
```

The cout statement prints nothing. What is this character that cout returns for 0 length token match? I have tried to check for '\0' but does not work. Please Help.

**EDIT: Complete Program to Validate IP Addresses**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int validateIP(string);
int main()
{
string IP;
cin>>IP;
int result=validateIP(IP);
if(result==0)
    cout<<"Invalid IP"<<endl;
if(result==1)
    cout<<"Valid IP"<<endl;
return 0;
}
//function definition validateIP(string)
int validateIP(string IP)
{
char ip[16];
int dotCount=0;
strcpy(ip,IP.c_str());
//check number of dots
for(int i=0;i<strlen(ip);++i)
{
    if(ip[i]=='.')
        {
            dotCount++;
        }
}
if(dotCount!=3)
    return 0;
//check range
char *numToken;
numToken = strtok (ip,".");
while (numToken!= NULL)
{
    int number;
    if(numToken!=NULL)          //check for token of length 0(e.g. case: ...)                                    
    number=atoi(numToken);      //i also checked for (numToken[0]!='\O')
    else return 0;
    if(number<0 or number>255)
        return 0;
    numToken=strtok (NULL,".");
}
return 1;
}
```

The program prints ValidIP for input: ...

Comment: Google for "malloc", you need to allocate memory for your pointer. (and it is written "piece" of code, not peace).

Comment: i was in hurry. Its piece now. Allocated Mem. But still?

Comment: By the way I thought your code was C, if it is C++ you should use new.

Comment: @Étienne: Here is the complete code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has **undefined behavior**, you haven't allocate memory for `points`, accessing it invokes UB.

Update, I might write `validateIP` by using string and STL functions only if I could. Mix C/C++ is not good for maintenance.

```
#include <sstream>

int to_int(const std::string& s)
{
  int i(0);
  std::stringstream ss(s);  
  ss >> i;     

  return i;
}

bool isValidIp(const std::string& IP)
{    
   if (std::count(IP.begin(), IP.end(), '.') != 3)
   {
      return false;
   }

   std:stringstream ss(IP);

   int token;
   std::string s;

   while(std::getline(ss, s, '.'))
   {
     int token = to_int(s);
     if (token < 0 || token > 255)
     {
       return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Then you call it:

```
 if (isValidIp(IP))
 {
     std::cout << "Valid IP" << std::endl;
 }
 else
 {
     std::cout << "Invalid IP" << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: OK now i have done it, so still what does strtok() return for tokens of length 0

Answer (score 1):

The `strtok` function returns sub-string of the given string delimited by the given character. IMO (to be tested) if your string only contains delimiting characters, the `strtok` function will return `NULL` (no more tokens) at the first call.

<s>Moreover in your code snippet, you copy the string to an uninitialized pointer. Replace your call to `strcpy` by a call to `strdup` for the underlying memory to be allocated before copying.</s> Edit: you modified your question as I were answering

Answer (score 1):

If the string only contains delimiting characters, `strok` return `NULL`

You probably want this:

```
int main()
{
  string dots=". . ."; //Notice space
  char *points=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
  char *p; // Use a char pointer
  strcpy(points,dots.c_str());
  p=strtok(points,".");
  while(p!=NULL)
 {
   cout<<points<<endl;
   p=strtok(NULL,".");
  }
 /* Free Memory */
 free(points);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget free ;-)

Answer (score 1):

strtok is used to tokenize the string. Say, i have a string "abc.def.ghi.jkl" then we can use strtok to get the tokens besed on the delimiter.

```
  char a[]="abc.def.ghi.jkl";
  char tmp=strtok(a, ".");
  if (tmp != NULL)   //Required because strtok will return null if it failes find the delimiter
     printf("\n value is [%s]", tmp); //out put is abc
```

So, in your case "..." is the string and '.' is the delimiter which result in empty string because there is no characters between first character and the delimiter '.'

your code will return empty string say "" as an output. for all the sttok function call.

Second you have to allocate memory to the points variable like

```
 char points[dots.length()+1];
```